# No VGA and sound driver installed in XP guest machine in Hyper-v virtualization?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have a Windows 10 host with 1 XP virtual machine using Hyper-v. However after installing XP for the guest machine, I don't see any VGA or sound driver, so the performance in guest machine is a little poor and no sound can be played, here is the screen shot of the Device manager:

[image]

You can see there is one entry listed involving sound in the pic but in fact the sound device is not working, I opened the *Sounds and Audio Devices* in Control Panel and here is what it shows:

[image]

It looks like drivers are missing but I don't know what to download. Technically I need to know about the hardware info but it is not even listed for me to see any piece of info to search for the drivers. I've tried googling around and found out about RemoteFX and Integration services but they seem to be used only in a Windows Server host. I've also seen some screen shot showing info about 1 video adapter called ***Microsoft Hyper-v Video*** but I'm not sure about the guest OS as well as how to make that available in my XP guest. I've tried googling for its driver but not found anything.

I hope someone here has experienced this issue to help me solve it. It's not really important currently but I think it may be in future. Also I'm fairly new to Hyper-v (switched from Virtual Box and VMWare, I can use VMWare again but totally disappointed with Virtual Box - the one caused 2 times of BSOD error on my host). Thank you!

Comment: Hyper-V only officially supports Windows XP with *Service Pack 3*; so ensure you install SP3 if the install disk didn't have it already.  After that "Install the integration services after you set up the operating system in the virtual machine."  So try those and let us know ([Info source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/dn792027.aspx))

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 the Windows XP is of Service Pack 3, I've already installed it on my guest machine. I'm not sure about how to install integration services though.

Comment: This guid https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/hh846766.aspx#BKMK_step4 talks about installing integration services but the Action menu in Virtual Machine Connection does not have any the so-called ***Insert Integration Services Setup Disk***.

Comment: After searching a bit looks like in Windows 10 there is no Integration Services Setup Disk menu available. Instead it has Enhanced Mode which is available only for guest installing Windows 8 and above. So looks like I'm stuck with Windows XP. The same problem (requesting for Insert Integration Services Setup Disk) can be found here http://www.tenforums.com/virtualization/17050-hyper-v-no-insert-integration-services-setup-disk-option.html

Answer (score 3):

What you need is the vmguest.iso from an older version of Hyper-V to install the Integration Components (IC).
You can get the IC from Hyper-V 2012/2012R2 Server, a free download, here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-hyper-v-server-2012-r2 (you’ll need to either find a way to extract it or install Hyper-V Server in a VM to get the vmguest.iso)

Or, if you’ve got a Windows 8/8.1/2012/2012R2 VM/system available with Hyper-V installed you’ll find it in the C:\windows\system32\ folder.

You could probably also use the vmguest.iso from Hyper-V Server 2008/2008R2 as well.

see: https://smudj.wordpress.com/2017/03/02/vmguest-iso-for-older-windows-oses-in-win102016/

---additional info added 2018Apr

I have updated the blog post listed above to include a download for the 2012R2 vmguest.iso file.  If you prefer a trusted source, download Hyper-V server 2012 R2 from Microsoft.  ( to extract, you’ll need to mount the ISO, open the x:\sources\install.wim file with something like 7zip, browse to Windows\system32, and extract the vmguest.iso or install Hyper-V Server in a VM to get the vmguest.iso)

The Integration Components will auto-install when you mount the vmguest.iso from Hyper-V 2012R2 and install drivers for the video card.  The other 2 devices are not needed.

The 2 remaining unknown devices are expected and can be ignored for OSes earlier than Windows Server 2012 R2.

Per Microsoft they are only supported on Windows Server 2012R2 OSes and higher:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2925727/unknown-device-vmbus-in-device-manager-in-virtual-machine-for-avma