# Can we run old games in a Hyper-V XP VM?

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

They're really old games that used to run on XP or earlier systems. And of course, many of them don't work as expected when running on newer systems.

I created a Gen1 XP VM with Hyper-V Manager and installed the Integration Components (see [Is it possible to get a Windows XP SP3 Hyper-V virtual machine properly working on Windows 10 Pro? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1316269/is-it-possible-to-get-a-windows-xp-sp3-hyper-v-virtual-machine-properly-working)). In the XP VM, I can see the display adapter enabled and I can access the internet. But I can't run any program except for those built-in ones. The programs either report an error or display messy mosaics.

I checked the MS official support list and know that the XP has been given up as it's really too old (so are those programs).

Also, sharing GPU is a problem. (remoteFX is removed and GPU partitioning doesn't support such old guest systems.

So I would like to know:

**Have any guys successfully run games on a Hyper-V XP VM?**

If yes, what is the magic that I missed?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question.   (1) Generation 1 machines have limited integration facilities. XP will not run in Generation 2 where integration is much better.  (2) XP is no longer updatable. So it does not seem possible to build a fully up to date XP machine.  I have one from years ago as a VMware VM because I built it when updates to XP were available. This is a big hill to climb today.

Comment: I have run once a game in a VMware Windows 7 VM and it worked fine. The only way to know if it'll work or not is to try it.

Comment: From a usability and user friendly perspective, VMware is much better than Hyper-V - I agree with Harrymc.   I have both (2 machines) and in Hyper-V both Generation 1 and Generation 2 machines.

Comment: Define "Old Games"

Comment: If your goal is playing old games, a dedicated emulator, such as something produced by Good Old Games or a DOS Emulator may be a better solution. Perhaps stepping back from your current work and reconsidering the assumptions you've made so far may find a better overall solution.